# Angular routing not working - 404 error not found

Tags: angular, routes

I have a simple Angular example where routing simply does not work. Every other component I already put in there works, but since today no other components work. When calling the path I always get "error 404 /test" form Angular CLI.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { EventAppComponent } from './events-app.component'
import { EventsListComponent } from './events/events-list.component'
import { EventThumbnailComponent } from './events/events-thumbnail.component'
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav/navbar.component'
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './events/event-details/event-details.component'
import { CreateEventComponent } from './events/create-event.component'
import { Error404Component } from './errors/404.component'
import { TestComponent } from './events/test.component'

import { EventService } from './events/shared/event.service'
import { ToastrService } from './common/toastr.service'
import { EventRouteActivator } from './events/event-details/event-route-activator.service'

import { appRoutes } from './route'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ], 
    declarations: [
        EventAppComponent,
        EventsListComponent,
        EventThumbnailComponent,
        EventDetailsComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        CreateEventComponent,
        Error404Component,
        TestComponent
    ],
    providers: [ EventService, ToastrService, EventRouteActivator ],
    bootstrap: [ EventAppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my route.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { EventsListComponent } from './events/events-list.component'
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './events/event-details/event-details.component'
import { CreateEventComponent } from './events/create-event.component'
import { Error404Component } from './errors/404.component'
import { EventRouteActivator } from './events/event-details/event-route-activator.service'
import { TestComponent } from './events/test.component'

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
    { path: 'events/new', component: CreateEventComponent },
    { path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent },
    { path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [EventRouteActivator] },
    { path: '404', component: Error404Component },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/events', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

test.component.ts (not working localhost:8808/test)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  template:
  `
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  `,
  styles: [``]
})

export class TestComponent {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Here is a working component (localhost:8808/404):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  template: `
    <h1 class="errorMessage">404'd</h1>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .errorMessage { 
      margin-top:150px; 
      font-size: 170px;
      text-align: center; 
    }`]
})

export class Error404Component {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

When renaming

```
{ path: '404', component: Error404Component },
```

to

```
{ path: '405', component: Error404Component },
```

I also get this error. What am I missing? When Strg+Click on the Component name VS Code takes me to the class so the filepath is correct I guess.

**EDIT:** I can also change

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/events', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

to

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/test', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

then I get redirect to the correct page @ localhost:8808/test. But after hitting enter again in the URL bar to directly go to this URL, it fails again.

Comment: do you get an error in the developer tools console? if so can you share

Comment: How are you navigating to the test route? What does your routerLink or `.navigate` look like?

Comment: @cacev000: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: @DeborahK: I just call it via localhost:8808/test like i do with localhost:8808/events or localhost:8808/404 (they both work). No .navigate or routerLink.

Comment: @Lpold ok and i am guessing you have this in your route file correct? 
                                                                                               
`@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})`

Comment: I have no exports array. Just the imports one. I've added the exports one but error still remains.

Answer (score -1):

so this is an example of what i have for routing module. is a bit different from what you have.

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login_Register',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'people'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'people',
        loadChildren: './people/people.module#PeopleModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

then in my **app.module.ts** i call the route file like this:

```
// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
  ],
  providers: [...],
  schemas: [..],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

hope this helps a little more